# PHP/mod rewrite to different files?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mod-rewrite

I am relatively new at php coding and am working to write my own MVC stuff. I'd rather do this than use a framework b/c I'll understand it much better this way :).

Currently, I have my site setup as follows:

domain.com/services

Will rewrite into index.php?page=services

Inside of index.php I have code that will load the correct template based on the URI string. However, I want to make my site a bit more complex than this...

I would like the server to load the appropriate php file based on the uri string. What is the best way to do this? Perhaps have the index.php actually read an execute another php file?

Thanks!

Edit: My current htaccess that handles what I'm doing now is:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
#RewriteBase

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.net$1 [R=301]

#remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:templates|configs|templates_c)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

What should I change to achive what i want? I was thinking just:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,NS]
```

And then:

```
list( $controller, $function, $params ) = explode( '/', $uri, 3 );
$params = explode( '/', $uri );
```

What would be a good php methodology to execute the right code at this point? just include the file?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use **.htaccess ModRewrite** for URL changes, so that you compact readable URLs will be correctly translated to your script paths

My own way to work in such situation:

```
RewriteRule  ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  engine.php?prmtrs=$1/$2 [L]

<?php
list($url_part, $url_page) = explode('/', $_GET['prmtrs']);
?>
```

Of cource you need to clean data from you $_GET befor use it, just simplified example to show idea more clear.

Comment: Already doing that. Added my .htaccess code. Any idea on how to add the functionality I asked about? Appreciate it!

Comment: I have added in my unswer above the approach I use in my own engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple rewrite rules based on the URIs. Here's a simple example - you can make more complex ones using RewriteCond.

```
# Rewrite all URIs beginning with 'a' to index1.php
RewriteRule ^(a[^/\.]+)/?$ index1.php?page=$1

# Rewrite all URIs beginning with 'b' to index2.php
RewriteRule ^(b[^/\.]+)/?$ index2.php?page=$1
```

If you really want different files to handle different types of URIs this is probably the way to go, unless you have dozens of such items. Otherwise you can figure out dispatching from within index.php

Comment: How would I do the dispatching from within index.php?

Comment: Well at that point you would simply figure out which controller class to instantiate and delegate it over to there.

Comment: Whats the best way to delegaet though? Include?

Comment: I would use require_once on the classes you may use.

Comment: So a switch statement hitting require_once on the appropriate classes?

Comment: You could do that, or you could just specify a directory on the include path that contains your controller classes. Fancier MVC frameworks differentiate between including and importing a class (lazy loading).

Comment: You may also want to look into autoloading: http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php